# request for member ‘a’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, arrays, struct, function-pointers

I looked through the previous posts on the topic to no avail. I'm attempting to access an `array` within a `struct` in an incorrect way and am getting the error `request for member ‘Days’ in something not a structure or union`.

The relevant line in my `.c`:

```
    bool isConflict(TimeSpan *timeA, TimeSpan *timeB, Class *classA[], Class *classB[])
    {       // Checking that days themselves conflict
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if ((classA->Days[i] == classB->Days[i]) && (classA->Days[i] != 0)){
                         doStuff;
    }
```

The error itself is happening at this bottom line in the way I'm attempting to access `Days[]`. Days itself is prototyped in my .h as such with `prototype`s :

```
    // TimeSpan is a previously created struct that is functioning correctly
    typedef struct Class
    {       TimeSpan timeSpan;
            int Days[7];
    } Class;

    bool isConflict(TimeSpan * a, TimeSpan * b, Class * classA[], Class * classB[]);
```

And lastly, my driver call looks like:

```
    if(isConflict(&EE315.timeSpan, &EE367.timeSpan, &EE315.Days[7], &EE367.Days[7]))
```

Thanks in advance for any help! - Allen

---

EDIT: Thanks to everyone including Floris and ooga for helping me out. Both of your tips were spot on and I appreciate it. - Allen

Comment: Is this C or C++? The use of `Class` is throwing me off...

Comment: Sorry, it's C. `Class` here is just a struct that I'm using for a class schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling with

```
if(isConflict(&EE315.timeSpan, &EE367.timeSpan, &EE315.Days[7], &EE367.Days[7]))
```

So your third argument is

```
&EE315.Days[7]
```

which is a pointer to element 7 of the array `Days`. What you want is

```
&EE315
```

That is a pointer to your structure... So the call becomes

```
if(isConflict(&EE315.timeSpan, &EE367.timeSpan, &EE315, &EE367))
```

See if that works for you.

Note also that you are declaring your function as

```
bool isConflict(TimeSpan * a, TimeSpan * b, Class * classA[], Class * classB[]);
```

You probably want to use

```
bool isConflict(TimeSpan * a, TimeSpan * b, Class * classA, Class * classB);
```

Since you are pointing to an element, not an array of elements (I think).

**afterthought**

It might be easier to change your code as follows:

```
bool isConflict( Class *a, Class *b ) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if ((a->Days[i] == b->Days[i]) && (a->Days[i] != 0)){
      doStuff;
    }
}
```

Since both `timeSpan` and `Days[]` are in fact part of the same structure. From a code readability perspective it's much better. And then you call it with

```
if(isConflict(&EE315, &EE367))
```

See how much neater that is?

Comment: Also, the parameter `classA` is declared as a pointer to a pointer: `Class *classA[]`.

Comment: @NikosC. I believe you are right. I was updating my anwer as you made your comment.

Comment: Thanks @Floris, I'm sure that will clear up issues after this current one but the compiler gets hung up on the error I posted which comes from the `.c` file. I'm pretty sure I'm prototyping something wrong in `bool isConflict(TimeSpan *timeA, TimeSpan *timeB, Class *classA[], Class *classB[])` or calling it incorrectly in `if ((classA->Days[i] == classB->Days[i]) && (classA->Days[i] != 0))`. Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: @AllenShultz - yes - you are passing a pointer to an array, not a class, when your prototype says `Class *classA[]`. If you just left off the `[]` the compiler would not complain until later...

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for keeping me honest. I meant to say "refers to", but you are right it is a _pointer_. Will correct my post.

Comment: @Floris Thanks. It is easy to confuse these kind of things when OP *again* writes in his imaginary language called "C/C++"... :/

Comment: @H2CO3 that's a little bit harsh... Perhaps there is a need for a formal 'language' - "`C+-`" perhaps? I see a lot of people write in that language already, but there is no tag for it...

Comment: @Floris All we (not we, they) need is more awareness. And precision -- sometimes even pedantry. Also, the world would be a better place without misleading/wrong tutorials that teach honest beginners terrible misconceptions from day one. I'm all against Internet censorship, but if I could restrict **one** thing on the Internet... that wouldn't be hate speech or "how to make a bomb" or porn... that would be *every* C and C++ tutorial that confuses the two languages.

Comment: @H2CO3 - as the old guy that still writes K&R '88 vintage code (although I have "modernized" to the extent that I no longer cast the return value of `malloc()`, and thank you for that), I can only agree with you. I find one language at a time confusing enough. And ban `void main()` while you're crusading.

Comment: @Floris Exactly, exactly. I can only hope this will get better over time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to have this prototype:

```
bool isConflict(TimeSpan * a, TimeSpan * b, int daysA[], int daysB[]);
```

and call it like this:

```
if(isConflict(&EE315.timeSpan, &EE367.timeSpan, &EE315.Days, &EE367.Days))
```

Obviously you'll have to change the definition of the function to access the new parameter type.